# What is the view that android show contact name in it, when you recive sms?

Tags: android, android-layout, sms

I'm working on an android sms app and now I'm going to create a dialog like android sms dialog. In android if you recive a message and you open it, android shows all your sms conversation with this sender. Now if in this list view you tap the screen, android show you a dialog that show you sender number and name. Now my question is that at first what kind of view is this? And second, how to create it for my app?
there are Pictures Of What I Want.
http://www.8pic.ir/images/96673565606491759523.jpg
http://www.8pic.ir/images/42920785388059988872.jpg